# Как вырезать svg из макета?

Tags: svg, photoshop

Как правильно вырезать `svg` из `psd` макета?
Через `Export as...` можно выбрать формат сохранение svg, а на деле сохраняет  картинку которая портится при масштабировании.

Читал что можно через `File > Extract Assets`, но такого меню у меня нет(версия CC 2015.1.1)

Comment: Вот же на хабре разбирали действующий способ. у меня заработало. https://habrahabr.ru/company/ua-hosting/blog/277673/

Answer (score 2):

Это самая плохая практика, на мой взгляд,- *рисовать в растровом редакторе, потом сохранять через плагин в векторном формате*.

- Дело в том, что `Photoshop` недостаточно точно присваивает стили
  элементам.
- Порою они перекрывают друг друга и противоречат сами себе.
- Изображения часто выходят за границу документа и поэтому обрезаются в
  SVG.
- Файл `SVG` выглядит просто чудовищно.
- Верстальщику потом нужно править этот файл вручную и очень часто, по ряду причин, ему не под силу сделать это. 
  В топиках на нашем сайте не раз поднимался вопрос о недопустимости применения фотошопа для изготовления векторных изображений:

[В каком виде дизайнер должен передавать верстальщику изображения SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758473/28748)

[Можно ли весь сайт делать на svg?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/753664/28748)

**Вывод один,- векторные изображения надо рисовать в векторном редакторе!**

Если не хватает желания освоить векторный редактор, то тем более не хватит сил и желания править файлы svg, сделанные в растровом редакторе.

Answer (score 0):

Если объект (векторный) создавался в Adobe Illustrator, а потом был перенесен в PSD макет, то уже при работе в Photoshop есть возможность открыть этот объект в Illustrator просто двойным кликом на объекте в окне со слоями.