# Можно ли весь сайт делать на svg?

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка, svg, кроссбраузерность

Что если html-верстку сайта сделать только с `svg` изображениями, вместо стандартных `img` или `png`, не будет никаких проблем? Кроссбраузерность и прочее?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Для SVG нужно указывать `viewBox` аттрибут, если вы хотите поведение svg, как картинки. Иначе svg не будет масштабироваться. Насколько это является проблемой - вам  решать. В остальном - современные [браузеры поддерживают svg давно](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg), можно не париться.

Вторая проблема - svg труднее сделать, чем png. Художники/дизайнеры как правило работают с растровой графикой: векторный svg скорее является в web полезным дополнением, нежели новым подходом.

Например под векторную графику был заточен `Flash`, но он сейчас не живой.

Answer (score 38):

> Можно ли весь сайт делать на svg?

Ответ - нет.
Так как вопрос поставлен слишком широко.
Если бы автор спросил,- *можно-ли сделать всю оформительскую графику, анимацию, интерактивную картографию на SVG?,* то ответ был-бы - ДА!
Так как формат SVG именно для этого и разработан.
Графика на сайте должна быть векторной, а не растровой.
Не хочется повторять избитые истины на тему,- что вектор легче по весу, а значит сайты летают быстрее. Вектор масштабируемый по определению, поэтому не надо особых ухищрений, чтобы сайт одинаково великолепно смотрелся, как  на маленьких экранах смартфонов, так и на гигантских видео панелях.

**26 февраля 2021 года** вышла официальная версия  [Scalable Vector Graphics SVG2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/)

Возможности SVG при этом значительно расширяются.  В частности, появился новый элемент `Mesh gradients`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конические градиенты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- *Отдельный разговор про анимацию `SVG SMIL`.*

Вот уже четыре года `Chrome` пишет, что smil "deprecated",-  в переводе означает, что он не одобряет  smil, но тем не менее продлевает каждый раз его [поддержку](https://caniuse.com/#search=smil).

Смотрите, это уже идет с 45 версии до 78 текущей версии `Chrome` и продлено уже сейчас, как минимум до [<strike>77</strike> далее  test on real browser 115-117 -- 23 августа 2023 года](https://caniuse.com/#search=smil) будущей версии. *Как говорится ничего нет более постоянного, чем временное.*
Почему это происходит, почему не закрывают smil и не закроют в ближайшее время?
Потому-что основные конкуренты: [CSS Animations Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/),  [Web Animations](https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/)        не дотягивают до уровня smil SVG.
Все виды, любой сложной CSS анимации с простынями кода, легко и просто реализуются в несколько строк на SVG.  Но наоборот, просто невозможно перевести некоторые примеры анимации SVG в CSS.
**Например: движение по криволинейному пути текста, объектов, маркеров.**

```html
  <svg  width="55%" height="55%"  viewBox="0 0 300 200" >
 
<defs>
<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    #startButton:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        fill:green;
        opacity: 0.5;
                    }
    #stop:hover{
        opacity: 0.5; 
               }     
         ]]> 
         
    
 </style>  
 <marker id="mark_path" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" 
        markerUnits="strokeWidth" orient="auto"
          markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3">
        <polyline points="0,0 10,5 0,10 1,5" fill="black" />
 </marker>
 
  <linearGradient id="grad1" x2="0%" y2="100%"
        spreadMethod="pad" >
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="skyblue"/>
  <stop offset="90%" stop-color="white"/> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen"/>
</linearGradient>

  <path id="balerina" transform="scale(0.05)  translate(-100 -200)"   d="M468 264c1 3 2 7 4 10 5 12 12 23 15 28s1 5 2 9c1 4 6 14 9 19 3 6 5 8 5 9 0 1-3 1-3 5s4 12 7 18 5 9 5 10c0 1-3 1-4 2 -2 2-3 5-5 7 -2 2-6 3-9 3 -3 0-6 0-8-1 -2-1-3-3-6-4 -2-1-5 0-8-2 -2-2-4-7-6-10 -2-3-5-4-7-6 -2-3-3-8-5-11 -2-3-5-5-7-8 -2-3-2-7-4-7 -1 0-3 4-5 10s-6 17-7 24 0 13-1 20c0 7-2 15-3 23 -1 8 0 16 2 30 2 14 5 34 9 49 3 14 6 23 7 32s0 19-2 28c-2 9-4 17-5 21s-2 5-4 6c-2 0-7 0-9-2 -2-2-1-6-1-12 0-6 0-15-2-21s-4-8-7-10c-3-3-6-5-8-9 -2-3-1-7 0-9 2-2 5-4 7-6 2-2 3-4 2-8 -1-3-2-8-7-17 -4-9-11-24-15-39s-3-32-4-45 0-21-1-35c-1-13-2-31-4-46 -1-15-3-28-4-36 -1-8-2-11-9-14 -7-4-20-8-36-14 -16-6-34-13-45-18 -12-6-17-10-24-15 -7-4-15-9-27-15 -11-6-26-15-37-20 -11-5-19-7-28-10 -9-3-21-8-31-13 -11-6-21-13-25-17s-2-6-1-8c2-2 3-3 9-3 6 0 17 3 27 7 10 4 20 9 26 13 6 4 9 6 12 8 4 2 9 5 22 8 13 3 33 8 47 13 14 5 22 12 29 16 7 4 13 5 25 7s33 3 41 3c9 0 7-1 6-3s-1-4-2-6c-1-2-4-4-5-6 -1-2-1-4-2-6s-4-5-5-8c-1-2-1-4-2-7s-3-5-4-7c-1-2 0-3-1-6 -1-2-2-6-2-9 0-3 1-6 2-8 0-3-1-5-1-7 1-2 3-4 6-4 2 0 5 1 6 1 1 0 2-2 3-3 2 0 4 1 6 1s3-1 5 1c2 2 6 6 9 8 2 3 3 4 4 4 1 0 1-1 2 0s3 5 6 8c2 4 4 7 5 8s1-1 2 0c1 1 4 4 6 8 3 4 5 7 7 9 2 1 2 1 4 2 2 1 4 5 8 10 1 1 2 3 3 4 2 0 2-4 1-8 -1-5-2-11-2-16 -1-6-1-11-1-15 0-4-1-7-3-9 -2-2-5-4-12-7 -7-3-16-6-23-8 -7-3-11-4-17-6 -6-1-15-3-24-6 -10-3-21-7-29-10 -8-3-13-4-17-3 -4 1-6 3-9 4 -3 1-7 1-10 1 -3 0-4 1-6 2s-3 0-4 0c-1 0-2-1-1-2 1-1 3-2 5-4 2-2 5-3 5-5 0-1-4-2-8-3 -5 0-11 1-15 2 -4 1-6 3-8 3 -2 1-4 1-5 0 -1-4 13-12 16-12 4-1 8-2 11-2 3-1 4-1 7 0 3 0 8 1 12 1s7 0 10 0c2 0 4 0 8 1 4 1 10 3 19 5s21 3 29 3c8 1 12 2 18 4 5 2 12 6 17 9 6 2 11 3 16 4s10-1 15 0c5 0 11 2 14 2 4 0 6 0 7-2 1-2 2-5 2-7 0-2-1-4-3-6 -2-2-6-3-11-6 -4-3-9-7-12-12 0-1-1-1-1-2l0 0c-3 1-6 0-8-1s-4-4-5-8c-1-4-1-10 1-14 2-4 5-7 8-8 3-1 5 0 7 2 0-1 1-1 1-2 4-4 9-7 13-9 4-2 8-2 13-3s8 0 13 1c4 1 8 4 11 7 2 3 3 6 4 9s4 4 6 5c2 1 4 2 4 3 0 1-2 3-3 4 -1 1-1 2 0 3s2 2 2 3c0 1 0 2 0 2s1 1 1 2c0 1 0 2 0 4 0 2 1 3 1 4 0 1 0 3-2 3 -2 1-7 2-10 4 -3 3-4 7-3 12 1 5 3 11 5 14 3 3 5 3 9 2 4-2 9-5 15-8 6-2 12-4 19-7 8-3 17-9 24-15 7-5 11-11 18-16s15-10 21-15c6-4 9-7 14-11 4-4 9-8 13-10 5-2 9-2 15-3 6 0 12-1 17-1 4 0 6-1 8-1 2 0 4 0 7 0 3 0 6 0 9 1 3 1 6 3 5 4 -1 1-4 0-11 0 -6 0-14 2-18 3 -4 1-2 2 0 4 2 1 6 3 7 4 1 1 1 2-1 2 -2 0-4 0-8-1 -4 0-10 0-15-1s-8-2-10-2 -3 1-5 2c-2 2-6 5-12 11 -6 6-15 15-22 22 -7 7-12 11-22 19 -10 8-25 18-35 25 -10 7-14 9-15 13 -1 4 1 9 1 18 0 9-3 22-8 34 -5 12-12 22-17 33 -6 11-11 21-13 32C469 262 468 263 468 264z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
     

 </defs>
    

   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="none" />

    <path id="t_path"  d="m28 30c16-18 51-12 72-1 35 18 34 79 66 96 32 17 79 24 102 0C291 102 295 43 266 25 194-19 112 177 38 136 7 118 4 56 28 30Z" marker-mid="url(#mark_path)" stroke="#c3c3c3" stroke-width="1" fill="none"   />


    
     
      <path transform="  scale(0.15) scale(-1 1) translate(-10 -200) " fill="black"  d="m142.2 23.5c9-0.1 3.7-16.5 10.9-17.7 2.9-0.5 4 1.1 6.3 2.3 0.1 2.4-1.7 2.9-2.3 4.6 2.1 1.8 3.6-0.6 5.7-0.6 0.7 4-5.3 3.2-6.9 1.7-1.2-2.1 0.4-3.4 1.1-5.1-8.1-3.6-5 5.1-6.3 9.7-1.9 6.9-12.7 10.8-13.7 1.1-0.6-5.9 7.4-13.1 1.1-16.6-4.8 3.8-7.4 10.2-10.3 16-5.1 10.2-10.6 22.9-16.6 32.6 0.4 2.8 3.6 2.9 4.6 5.2 0.6 2.7-3.4 0.8-2.9 3.4 3.3 0.6 6.7-1.3 8.6-3.4 1.1-1.2 0.8-2.7 1.7-4 3.3-4.9 8-6.3 14.9-8.6 1.6-4 6.2-5.7 10.9-5.1 2-0.9 2.3-3.4 3.4-5.1 2.6-2.4 7.2-2.7 9.7-5.1-0.4-2.1-2.9-2.8-0.6-4.6 3.3-0.5 2.9 2.8 2.9 5.7-3 3-8.4 3.5-10.3 7.4 1.6 0.9 2.6 0 4.6 1.1 1.9-1.2 1.6-4.6 3.4-5.7 6.8-0.2 6.8-7.3 9.2-12 4.1 1.3-0.7 9.4-2.3 10.9-1.9 1.8-4.3 2-5.7 2.3-0.9 3.1-2.2 5.8-4.6 7.4-2 0.3-1.4-2-3.4-1.7-3 3-4.4 7.4-10.9 6.9-1.8 4.9-10.3 3-14.3 5.7-0.3 9.7-10.3 12.6-18.9 12 5.6 9.6 18 2.1 24.6-2.3 1.4-0.9 3-1.4 4.6-2.3 2.8-1.7 5.2-4.3 8-5.7 6.9-3.4 22.5-6 31.5-1.1-1.8 6.1-13.2-0.5-15.4 4.6 3.6 2.4 8.1 0.2 12 0.6 6.1 0.6 12.3 3.9 20.6 3.4 2.3 0.9 3 3.5 6.3 3.4 1.2 4.7 9.6 2.2 9.2 8.6-6.5 0.7-11.5-4.4-17.7-4.6-2.1-0.1-4.2 1.3-6.3 1.1-2.8-0.2-5.3-2.5-8-2.9-7.7-1-13.9 4.7-21.7 4.6-3.2 0-6.6-2.6-9.7-0.6 2.2 5 12 2.5 17.7 4 2.1-0.4 1.4 2 2.3 2.9 3.6-0.4 5.4 1 5.7 4 0.7 2.4-2.4 1-2.9 2.3 3 4.5 11.9 3 13.2 9.2-4.7 2.4-9.6-1.5-14.3-1.7-1.4-0.1-3.2 0.7-4.6 0.6-4.6-0.5-8.3-3.1-11.4-5.1-8.6-1.2-15.9 1.6-22.9 0-5.6-1.3-8.8-7.6-13.7-8.6-1.4 3.8 2.4 7 5.7 8 4.8 5.7 11.3 9.7 17.2 14.3 0.7 2.4 2.1 4 2.9 6.3 0.6 3.1-1.9 3-1.7 5.7 9.8 0.3 25-0.3 33.8 0 0.8 1 1.5 1.9 1.1 4-0.5-6.1 5.8-7.5 11.4-5.7 1 0.3 0 2.7 1.1 2.9 1.8 0.5 0.8-1.9 1.7-2.3 2 0.3 3.2-0.2 4.6-0.6 1.4 0.5 3.3 0.5 3.4 2.3 1.7 0 0.6-2.9 2.3-2.9 5.9-1.2 11.2-1.9 15.5-4.6 2.6-1.7 4.1-5.7 7.4-4.6 2-0.1 0.8 2.3 1.1 3.4 0.6 2.1 1.9 3.8 2.3 6.9 0.1 1.4-0.3 2.4-1.1 2.9 2.6 2.5-0.1 3.6 1.1 7.4 0.5 1.8-1.5 1.2-1.7 2.3-0.4 2.3 1.5 2.3 1.1 4.6-6.3 4.8-9.8-3.8-18.9-6.9-1.6-0.5-3.3-0.2-4.6-0.6-2.9-0.9-5-2.3-10.3-1.1-1.4-0.7-2.7-1.5-3.4-2.9-1.6 3.9-10.9 3.7-13.2 0.6-23-0.1-45 0.2-65.2-0.6 2.3 5.3 9 6.2 11.4 11.4 5.8 2.5 12.4 3.9 17.7 6.3 7 3.2 11.6 8.5 14.9 16 1.9-0.3 2.7 0.4 4 0.6 3.9 8.1 20.8 3.2 26.9 9.2 1.5-0.1-0.8-1 0-2.3 2.6 1.7 3.1 4.8 5.2 6.9 2 2 5.3 2.7 7.4 4.6 1.2 1 5.5 5.9 6.3 7.4 3.8 7.9 0.3 19.3-6.3 22.9-3.7 2-10.7 3.3-17.7 2.9-14.9-0.8-28.6-11.6-46.9-12.6-11.4-0.6-23.7 3-32.6 5.7-7.5 2.3-13.1 4.9-18.9 9.7-1.5 2.5-4 4.1-6.9 5.1-1.6-4.6 4.6-6.5 5.7-10.3 5.6-2.8 11.2-5.6 16.6-8.6 7.5-1.7 15.4-4.4 23.5-5.1 3.6-0.3 7.2 0.9 10.3-1.1 4.9 2 8.4 0.6 13.2 1.1 1.9 0.2 4.1 1.4 6.3 1.7 7.8 1 12.9 3.1 21.7 5.2 5.9 1.3 14.8 6.4 22.9 3.4 4.3-1.5 6.4-7.2 5.7-13.2-0.8-6.5-8.6-15.3-15.4-18.3-3.6-1.6-7.7-0.9-10.3-3.4-1.8-0.5-1.2 1.5-2.3 1.7-13.2-1.4-23.6-3.8-30.3-10.9-3.5-3.7-7.1-8.3-12.6-10.9-0.1 5.3 9.5 5.8 10.9 11.4-4-1.2-8-4.1-12.6-5.1-3.9-0.9-8.4-0.6-12-1.7-5.7-1.8-8.9-6-13.7-8-1-3.8-4.3-5.2-5.1-9.2-5.6-2-9.4-5.8-10.9-12-8.1 0.5-15.2 0.1-22.9 0-20-0.2-42 1.6-64.7-0.6-0.6-1.5-0.1-2.9 0.6-4.6 5.7 0.9 9.9 0 16 0 6.9-4.2 13.5-8.6 17.7-15.4-1.6-3-7.9-1.3-8.6-5.1-1.6 0.1-1.6 1.8-2.9 2.3-1.9-0.2-1.1-3.1-2.3-4 1.5-1.6 5.5-0.1 6.3-3.4-0.1-2.8-4-1.7-2.9-5.7 3-0.3 2.6 2.8 4 4 4.5 0.9 3.1-4.2 6.9-4 0.3 3.6 0.5 5.6 3.4 5.7 3.7 0.1 4.6-5.4 4.6-8 4.4-0.9 8.2-1.5 12-1.7-2.3-3.4-2.8-8.6-4.6-12.6 1.6-2.5 0.5-5.2 1.1-7.4 1.1-3.7 4-6.2 5.7-9.7 0.3-1.1-0.8-3.4 1.1-2.9-0.5-1.5-1.2-2.4-1.1-4 0.1-1.3 1.9-3.6 2.9-5.1 0.1-0.1 0.4-2.2 0.6-2.3 1.1-0.9 4.1-0.5 4.6-1.1 1.3 6.2 0.8 14.5-2.3 20.6-1.1 2.1-0.9 4.5-2.9 6.3 0.2 2.4 2 5.4 0 8.6 1.6 4.2 1.3 7.8 0.6 12.6-0.1 0.6 0.6 1.7 0.6 1.7-0.6 2.9-2.8 4.1-3.4 6.9-0.4 1.7 0.2 3.6 0 5.2-0.9 8.6-7.1 11.6-10.9 18.3 6.6 2.8 6.1-1.3 10.3-4.6 1.6-1.2 3.8-1.5 4.6-2.3 2.3-2.2 3-6.1 6.3-8 1.5-0.9 3.9-1.5 5.7-2.3 4.3-1.8 10.2-4 14.3-8 2.5-2.4 3-5.2 6.3-6.9 0.4-2.9 1.7-4.7 2.3-7.4 2.6-1.6 4.4-3.9 5.7-6.9-2.1-1.8-2.1 2.1-5.1 1.1-1.7-1.8-2.6-4.2-5.1-5.1-3.5 0.8-6.5 4.9-10.9 2.9 0.8-5.3 6.8-5.4 10.9-7.4-0.2-3.8-6.8-1.2-7.4-4.6 1.6-3.7 8.6-2 12-4 14.4-15.2 26.5-32.7 40.1-48.6 2.9 1.8 5.8 2.9 6.3 5.7 1 5.2-7.8 13.2-1.1 17.7zm1.1 20.6c1.2-1 4.7 0.1 5.7-1.1-2.1-0.4-5.2-1.3-5.7 1.1zm-26.3 55.5c-4.3-4.3-9.5-10.5-15.4-8.6-5.3 1.7-9.9 13.4-17.2 13.2-0.3 1.8-1.1 3.1-1.1 5.2 1.8 0.9 2 3.3 5.2 2.9 1.1-9 10-12.6 20.6-11.4 4.8 0.5 9.3 4.2 13.2 2.3-0.7-2.2-2.6-3.1-5.1-3.4zm-69.2-8.6c-2.2 4.2-5 8-9.7 9.7-2.3 5.9-9.4 7-12 12.6 4-0.6 8.5-0.7 13.2-0.6 5.8-4.8 16.2-12.4 12-21.7-1.1 0-2.3 0-3.4 0zm36.1 6.9c-3.2 3.7-10 3.8-14.3 6.3 0.3 4.5-3.3 5.1-4 8.6 2.3 0.9 5.3-1.1 6.9-2.3 4.4-3.4 7.8-8.8 12.6-11.4-0.1-0.7-0.2-1.4-1.1-1.1zm-25.7 14.9c2.2 1.1 4.5 0.3 4-2.9-2 0.2-3.1 1.4-4 2.9zm17.7 0c2.1-0.5 2.8 1.3 4 0 0.2-2.9-4-2.7-4 0zm49.2 23.5c0.8-1.7 0.5-3.3-1.7-3.4 0.5 1.3 0.3 3.1 1.7 3.4zm5.2 6.3c-0.3-2.3-1.3-4.1-3.4-4.6-1.3 2 1.6 3.9 3.4 4.6z" fill-rule="evenodd">
     <animateMotion  begin="startButton.mouseover+0.1s" end="stopRed.mouseover"
         dur="18s" repeatCount="1" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
         <mpath xlink:href="#t_path" />
    </animateMotion>
     </path>

<use xlink:href="#balerina"  style="fill:orangered;"  >
     <animateMotion  begin="startButton.mouseover+0.25s" end="stopOrangered.mouseover"
         dur="6s" repeatCount="2" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
         <mpath xlink:href="#t_path" />
    </animateMotion>
</use>  

<use xlink:href="#balerina"  style="fill:purple;" >
     <animateMotion  begin="startButton.mouseover+0.25s" end="stopTeal.mouseover"
         dur="8s" repeatCount="2" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
         <mpath xlink:href="#t_path" />
    </animateMotion>
</use>

    
<g  id="startButton" transform="scale(0.7) translate(-20 220)" >
<rect  x="20" y="20" rx="3" ry="3" width="60" height="20" fill="deepskyblue" />
<text  x="50" y="35" font-size="16" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial" text-anchor="middle" 
fill="white" >Start</text> 
</g>
 <g transform="translate(95 -5)">
<g id="stop" fill-opacity="1" > 
   <rect  x="180" y="140" rx="3" ry="3" width="20" height="60" fill="none" stroke-width="2px" stroke="#c3c3c3" />           
    <g id="stopRed" >
        <circle  r="6" cx="190" cy="150" fill="none" stroke="black"  /> 
        <circle  r="4" cx="190" cy="150" fill="black"  />   
    </g>    
        <g id="stopOrangered" >
            <circle  r="6" cx="190" cy="170" fill="none" stroke="black"  /> 
            <circle  r="4" cx="190" cy="170" fill="orangered" stroke="orange"  />   
        </g>
    <g id="stopTeal" >
        <circle r="6" cx="190" cy="190" fill="none" stroke="black"  />  
        <circle  r="4" cx="190" cy="190" fill="darkblue" stroke="orange"  />    
    </g>        
    
</g>
    <text  x="170" y="170"  transform="rotate(-90 170,170)" 
      font-size="18" font-weight="bold" font-family="serif" text-anchor="middle" fill="gray"  >Stop
    </text>
</g>    
</svg>
```

Ещё пример

**Анимация ссылок с помощью кривых Безье**

*анимация начинается при наведении курсора на ссылку*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 
 </head>
 
 <body>  
 <style>
  svg {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/hawaii-beach.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  width:50%
  height:50%
  }
 </style>
  
 <svg   viewBox="0 0 600 500">
    
 
<defs> 
 <path id="Lsvg" d="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200" style="stroke:teal;fill-opacity:0.3;stroke-width:3;fill:none">
<animate begin="animLink.mouseover"  dur="10s" restart="whenNotActive"  attributeName="d" 
values="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,100 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,300 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200"/> 
</path>

</defs>
<text text-anchor="middle" font-size="25" fill="#026282">
      <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#Lsvg"><tspan dy="-20">So easy to do with SVG just  few lines</tspan></textPath>
<animate begin="animLink.mouseover"   dur="10s" repeatCount="1" attributeName="fill"
values="red;green;red;green;red"/>
</text>
<use xlink:href="#Lsvg" transform="translate(0 -10)"/>
   
  <rect id="animLink" x="100" y="150" width="400" height="60" fill="#E0E0E0" fill-opacity="0.01" stroke="none" />  

    </svg>
 </body>
 </html>
```

- SVG и CSS очень хорошо дополняют друг друга. CSS включил в свои
  правила атрибуты и параметры SVG.

Например: для окраски строк, заполнение цветом элементов svg,  в css добавлено `stroke:#`, `fill:#`

[**Перечень всех атрибутов, которые можно использовать и в SVG и в CSS**](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html)

### Update 20.10.2018

[Ссылка на сайт](https://emacsformacosx.com/), сделанный полностью на SVG:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «избитые истины на тему,- что вектор легче по весу, а значит сайты летают быстрее» — а с чего это вдруг истина? Браузер вынужден тратить драгоценное процессорное время на растеризацию вектора, в то время как растровые картинки уже, как бы сказать, растеризованы

Comment: @andreymal вы серьезно насчет растерезации svg? Можете указать источник, где это сказано?

Comment: Эм, что именно сказано? Для вас неочевидно, что линии, круги, прямоугольники и прочие фигуры нужно преобразовывать в пиксели для отображения на мониторе, состоящем из пикселей? Или что?

Comment: @andreymal если не лень почитайте эту статью http://vector-conversions.com/vectorizing/raster_vs_vector.html

Comment: Почитал, опровержения своим словам я там не нашёл. То, что там написано, проходят в школе на уроках информатики, и известно каждому, кто их не прогуливал, в том числе и мне. Зачем я это читал?

Comment: @andreymal поэтому я и писал в этом посте, что это всё "избитые истины" - насчет преимущества векторного формата перед растровым. А вот ваше утверждение, что растровый формат нагружает процессор намного меньше, чем векторный,- довольно спорно. Вам хочется сделать тесты производительности? Мне,- нет Я читал отчёты о таких тестах.

Comment: Во-первых, про преимущества векторного формата я ничего не говорил — я говорил только про «летают быстрее»; во-вторых, ваше утверждение о спорности меньшей нагрузки от растрового формата тоже спорно. Отчёты о тестах — особенно на мобильных устройствах — прекрасно дополнят ваш ответ :)

Comment: @andreymal вам лень самому поискать, мне тоже лень. Хотите оставить за собой последнее слово? Ищите пожалуйста. Если я ошибаюсь, то легко признаю свою ошибку :-)

Comment: После подобных ответов прямо и хочется уйти во front-end и разобраться со всеми подобными вкусностями)

Comment: Вот и на хороший ответ набралось =)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, нагружает ли систему smil svg анимация, влияет ли как-то на производительность?

Comment: @HamSter Особой разницы в производительности анимации средствами `smil` и css не замечал. Но `smil` может намного больше по сравнению c CSS анимацией. Некоторые фильтры SVG, если они применяются к большим пространствам могут вызвать проблемы с производительностью. Проблем нет, если применять фильтры для получения окраски объектов, для теней, бликов

Comment: Пример "Анимация ссылок с помощью кривых Безье" не работает на Firefox 115.  Всё, прошла эпоха SVG?  Или это можно пофиксить?

Comment: Сорри, пример работает, но не сразу.  Наверное, это связано с недоступностью картинки, прописанной в `background-image: url` (кстати, некоторые российские интернет-провайдеры блокируют `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`)

Comment: @ESkri У меня установлена самая свежая версия FF - 117.0.1 (64-разрядный) и Пример "Анимация ссылок с помощью кривых Безье"  работает. Действительно в FF пример сайта  загружается теперь медленно, но это от нас не зависит

Answer (score 10):

Если сайт предназначен не для чтения, а это веб приложение, например для рисования или игра, то на мой взгляд его **НУЖНО** делать как минимум при помощи **SVG**.

Еще есть **CANVAS** он приходит на помощь когда **SVG** начинает медленно работать из-за того, что это все-таки **DOM** элементы, или когда возможностей **SVG** недостаточно (3D графика).

---

**Перимущества SVG:**

1. Все то что вытекает из того что SVG векторный формат с довольно несложным синтаксисом,  те позволяет легко создавать элементы "сложной формы".
2. Простота взаимодействия - за счет поддержки DOM событий, поддержка CSS, все как с HTML элементами.
3. Богатейшие встроенные возможности работы с фильтрами, масками, анимациями.

---

**Недостатки SVG:**

1. Все-таки это DOM структура, и если она большая, то скорость рендеринга может упасть.
2. Разная поддержка спецификации в разных браузерах/устройствах.
3. Сложновато, по сравнению с **HTML** верстать обычный текст, однако никто не запрещает использовать для этого обычный же **HTML**

---

Пример, редактор сплайнов и симметрия, смотрите развернутым:

[image: spline symmetry]

```js
let size = 800;

let color = d3.scaleLinear(d3.schemeCategory10)

var points = d3.range(0, 5).map(function(i) {
  return [
      size/2 - Math.sin(i/3)*100*Math.random(), 
      size/2 + i*(33+33*Math.random())];
});

let dragged = null,
    selected = points[points.length-1];

let line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal);

let svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", size)
    .attr("height", size);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", size)
    .attr("height", size)
    .on("mousedown", mousedown);

let copies = svg.append("g");

let path = svg.append("path")
    .style("stroke", 'red')
    .datum(points)
    .classed("line", true);

d3.select(window)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup);

fillCopies();
redraw();

d3.select('#axes').on('input', redraw)

function fillCopies() {
    
  copies.html('');
  let axes = d3.select('#axes').node().value;
  for (let i = 0; i < axes; i++) {
      
      let transformValue = `
        translate(${size/2} ${size/2}) 
        rotate(${i*(360/axes)}) 
        translate(${-size/2} ${-size/2})
      `;
      
       axes-1&&copies.append("line")
        .attr('x1', -size)
        .attr('y1', size/2)
        .attr('x2', size/2)
        .attr('y2', size/2)
        .attr('transform', transformValue)
      
      i && copies.append("path")
        .style('stroke', color(i/axes))
        .attr('transform', transformValue)
        .datum(points)
        .classed("line", true)
  
  }
}


function redraw() {
    
  fillCopies();
    
  svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", line);  

  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle.knob")
      .data(points, d => d);

  circle.exit()
      .remove();
    
  let newNodes = circle.enter()
      .append("circle")
      .classed('knob', true)
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .on("mousedown", d => { 
          selected = dragged = d; 
          redraw(); 
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("r", 6.5);

  circle.merge(newNodes)
      .classed("selected", d => d === selected)
      .attr("cx", d => d[0])
      .attr("cy", d => d[1]);

  if (d3.event) {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
  }
}

function mousedown() {
  points.push(selected = dragged = d3.mouse(svg.node()));
  redraw();
}

function mousemove() {
  if (!dragged) 
      return;
  let m = d3.mouse(svg.node());
  dragged[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(size, m[0]));
  dragged[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(size, m[1]));
  redraw();
}

function mouseup() {
  if (!dragged) 
      return;
  mousemove();
  dragged = null;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

rect {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

line {
   stroke: gray; 
   stroke-dasharray: 5 10;
}

circle,
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

circle {
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .2;
  cursor: move;
}

.selected {
  fill: #ff7f0e;
  stroke: #ff7f0e;
}

.ui {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-shadow:  0 1px 1px 0 lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui">
<input type="range" min=1 max=99 value=3 id="axes"></input>
</div>
<svg></svg>
```

---

**Приемущества CANVAS:**

1. Наличие 2D и 3D контекста.
2. Практически безграничные возможности графического программирования, тут все зависит от Вас, будет это работать быстро или нет.
3. Возможность утилизировать мощность видеокарты, причем не только для графики, но и для [расчетов](https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js).
4. Вы сможете открыть для себя нечто новое в (веб) программировании =)

---

**Недостатки CANVAS:**

1. Относительно сложный(2D) и очень сложный(3D) API. (Высокий порог вхождения)
2. Отсутствие механизмов взаимодействия с элементами, т.е. Вам самим надо проверять где пользователь возит мышкой и самим реагировать на это.
3. Сложность отладки. (Ничего вы не посмотрите в инспекторе итд)

---

Пример: 3D фрактал - [Губка Менгера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), получен при помощи [трассировки лучей во фрагментном шейдере](https://iquilezles.org/www/articles/menger/menger.htm).

В примере реализованы:

- освещение/затенение по фонгу подвижным источником света
- [мягкие тени](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/rmshadows/rmshadows.htm)
- [ambient occlusion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/954746/188366)

управление:

drag = rotate

scroll = zoom

[image: menger sponge]

```js
let fragCode = [...document.scripts].find(s => s.type === "frag").textContent;

let fst = FullScreenTriangle(fragCode);
let resolution = fst.triangleProgram.uniform('2f', 'resolution');
let time = fst.triangleProgram.uniform('1f', 'time');
let eye = fst.triangleProgram.uniform('3f', 'eye');
let lightPos = fst.triangleProgram.uniform('3f', 'lightPos');
let started = new Date().getTime();

Mouse3D.init();

animate();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    drawFrame();
}

function drawFrame() {
    let t = (new Date().getTime() - started)/1000;
    resolution.set(fst.gl.drawingBufferWidth, fst.gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    time.set(t);
    eye.set(Mouse3D.eye[0], Mouse3D.eye[1], Mouse3D.eye[2]);
    lightPos.set(Math.cos(t/3)*0.8,0,Math.sin(t/3)*0.8);
    fst.draw();
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/strangerintheq/glx@0.0.2/js/glx.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/strangerintheq/glx@0.0.2/js/ShaderLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/strangerintheq/glx@0.0.2/js/FullScreenTriangle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/strangerintheq/glx@0.0.2/js/mouse3d.js"></script>

<script type="frag">

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec3 eye;
uniform vec3 lookAt;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform float time;

float sdBox( vec3 p, vec3 b ){
  vec3 d = abs(p) - b;
  return length(max(d,0.0))
         + min(max(d.x,max(d.y,d.z)),0.0); 
}

vec3 sponge( in vec3 p ){
   float d = sdBox(p,vec3(1.0));
   vec3 res = vec3( d, 1.0, 0.0 );
   float s = 1.;
   for( int m=0; m<6; m++ )  {
      vec3 a = mod( p*s, 2.0 )-1.0;
      s *= 3.0;
      vec3 r = abs(1.0 - 3.0*abs(a));
      float da = max(r.x,r.y);
      float db = max(r.y,r.z);
      float dc = max(r.z,r.x);
      float c = (min(da,min(db,dc))-1.0)/s;
      if( c>d ) {
          d = c;
          res = vec3( d, 0.2*da*db*dc, (1.0+float(m))/4.0);
       }
   }
   return res;
}

vec2 map(vec3 p) {
    vec3 r =sponge(p);
    return vec2(r.x, abs(r.y - r.z));
}

vec3 rayDirection(float fieldOfView, vec2 size) {
    vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy - size / 2.0;
    float z = size.y / tan(radians(fieldOfView) / 2.0);
    return normalize(vec3(xy, -z));
}

mat4 viewMatrix(vec3 eye, vec3 center, vec3 up) {
 vec3 f = normalize(center - eye);
 vec3 s = normalize(cross(f, up));
 vec3 u = cross(s, f);
 return mat4(
  vec4(s, 0.0),
  vec4(u, 0.0),
  vec4(-f, 0.0),
  vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1)
 );
}

vec2 castRay( vec3 ro, vec3 rd ) {
    float tmin = 0.01;
    float tmax = 32.0;
    float t = tmin;
    float m = -1.0;
    for ( int i=0; i<64; i++ ) {
     float precis = 0.0001*t;
     vec2 res = map( ro+rd*t );
        if ( res.x<precis || t>tmax )
            break;
        t += res.x;
     m = res.y;
    }
    if ( t>tmax )
        m=-1.0;
    return vec2( t, m );
}

const float NORMAL_EPSILON = 0.0005;

vec3 estimateNormal(vec3 pos) {
    vec2 e = vec2(1.0,-1.0)*0.5773*NORMAL_EPSILON;
    return normalize( e.xyy*map( pos + e.xyy ).x +
       e.yyx*map( pos + e.yyx ).x +
       e.yxy*map( pos + e.yxy ).x +
       e.xxx*map( pos + e.xxx ).x );
}

const vec3 K_a = vec3(.5, .5, .5);
const vec3 K_d = vec3(.5, .5, .5);
const vec3 K_s = vec3(.1, .1, .1);
const float shininess = 3.5;
const vec3 lightIntensity = vec3(1., 1., 1.);

vec3 phongContribForLight(vec3 k_d, vec3 k_s, float alpha, vec3 p, vec3 N, vec3 eye,
                          vec3 lightPos, vec3 lightIntensity) {

    vec3 L = normalize(lightPos - p);
    vec3 V = normalize(eye - p);
    vec3 R = normalize(reflect(-L, N));
    float dotLN = dot(L, N);
    float dotRV = dot(R, V);
    if (dotLN < 0.0) {
        return vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
    if (dotRV < 0.0) {
        return lightIntensity * (k_d * dotLN);
    }
    return lightIntensity * (k_d * dotLN + k_s * pow(dotRV, alpha));
}

vec3 phongIllumination(vec3 k_a, vec3 k_d, vec3 k_s, float alpha, vec3 p, vec3 nor, vec3 eye, vec3 materialColor) {
    vec3 color = materialColor * k_a;
    color += phongContribForLight(k_d, k_s, alpha, p, nor, eye, lightPos, lightIntensity);
    return color;
}

vec3 decodeMaterial(float m) {
    return vec3(1.-m/3.);
}

vec3 phong(vec3 p, vec3 nor, vec3 eye, float material) {
    vec3 materialColor = decodeMaterial(material);
    return phongIllumination(K_a, K_d, K_s, shininess, p, nor, eye, materialColor);
}

float softShadow( in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd, in float mint, in float tmax ){
 float res = 1.0;
    float t = mint;
    for( int i=0; i<16; i++ ) {
  float h = map( ro + rd*t ).x;
        res = min( res, 8.0*h/t );
        t += clamp( h, 0.02, 0.10 );
        if( res<0.005 || t>tmax ) break;
    }
    return clamp( res, 0.0, 1.0 );
}

float ao( vec3 pos, vec3 nor ){
 float occ = 0.0;
    float sca = 1.0;
    for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        float hr = 0.01 + 0.12*float(i)/4.0;
        vec3 aopos =  nor * hr + pos;
        float dd = map( aopos ).x;
        occ += -(dd-hr)*sca;
        sca *= 0.95;
    }
    return clamp( 1.0 - 3.0*occ, 0.0, 1.0 );
}

void drawScene(vec3 pt, float material) {
    vec3 nor = estimateNormal( pt );
    float occ = ao( pt, nor );
    float shadow = softShadow( pt, normalize(lightPos-pt), 0.1, 22.2);
    vec3 color = phong(pt, nor, eye, material)*sqrt(occ);
    color += color * shadow;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}

void main(void) {
 vec3 direction = rayDirection(60.0, resolution);
    mat4 viewToWorld = viewMatrix(eye, lookAt, vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    vec3 worldDir = (viewToWorld * vec4(direction, 0.0)).xyz;
    vec2 dist = castRay(eye, worldDir);
    if (dist.x > 32.) {
         gl_FragColor = vec4(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
    } else {
        drawScene(eye + dist.x * worldDir, dist.y);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: отличный ответ (+)

Comment: ну не смог не поделиться приятной новостью, что наконец-то SVG2 вплотную подошёл к финальному релизу. Там очень много по настоящему достойных вещей приготовлено.

Comment: == Так прямо в ответе, эту ссывлку и обновлял - "4 марта 2019 года вышла официальная версия [Scalable Vector Graphics SVG2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/)

Comment: `3D фрактал` он проста божественный .Слов нет.Если бы у меня было возможность дать 50 плюсов я бы дал!

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов есть поинтереснее, но готовых сниппетов нет https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO5fXGqeM5c

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Из всех твоих шедевров который я тут видел мне больше всего нравится этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861984/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов вот над чем я последнее время тружусь https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/OKVVOW

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Это проста небо и все ?красиво конечно но огневое кольцо лучше :)

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов да это трассировочка объемных облаков в реальном времени, я скоро к ландшафту приступлю, это отдельные куски, из которых потом буду клеить сцену, просто облака в хорошем качестве трассировать накладно, я их планирую растягивать раза в 2-3 и накладывать поверх хайрез сцены

Comment: @Alexandr_TT виновато мое природное любопытство :) я в курсе что его бросили на долго время (забыл на сколько лет  ) в вашем блоге читал :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT так Вы не админ :) ок

Comment: @Alexandr_TT парочку галочек я проставил :))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT все узнают ваше истинное лицо :))  могу снова пробежать по ответам и их отменить