# Как сделать огненное кольцо вокруг кнопки?

Tags: canvas

Как сделать вокруг кнопки огонь?

Типа этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел код на `canvas`, не знаю как уменьшить размеры и подогнать под кнопку, код
[тут](https://codepen.io/avdoshka/pen/bGwvWWy?editors=0010)

Comment: Код по ссылке может "подвесить" слабые компы.

Comment: Тебе обьязательно нужен код в канвасе?

Comment: Или просто нужна такая кнопка?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/861984/188366

Comment: Можеш брать gif пламя натянуть на него кнопку и почти все

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать круглый эффект огня при наведении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861984/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2):

Если пример ниже не подходит и нужно больше схожести, то дайте знать.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.btn {
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 8px solid #9D7037;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #d06d0c;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #d06d0c 0%, black 65%);
}

.flame {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, red, orange);
  border-radius: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  animation: 0.1s flame infinite;
  filter: blur(10px);
  position: relative;
  border: 45px solid black;
  border-left-width: 25px;
  border-top-width: 25px;
}
.flame:after, .flame:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, red, orange);
  animation: 0.2s flame infinite;
  transform: scale(0.8) rotate(20deg);
  border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  top: 20px;
}
.flame:before {
  top: 0;
  animation-duration: 0.09s;
  transform: scale(0.9) rotate(-15deg) translate(10px, 0px);
}

@keyframes flame {
  0% {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = "flame"></div>
<div class = "btn"></div>
```

Comment: Это разве похоже на то что я хотел увидеть это не то смотрите изображение

Answer (score -1):

Меняйте в css

```
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
```

Comment: Это не работает