# Как добавить растровое изображение в SVG и позиционировать на нем объекты?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Кто может подсказать вот какую штуку. На странице есть изображение, которое увеличивается в зависимости от размера экрана. И на нем есть объекты [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос в том. как отпозиционировать эти объекты, чтобы они не слетали когда изображение увеличивается?
Вот тут это реализовано(на последнем экране перед футером) https://straticainternational.com/products/broadway?variant=17254881820761 ,но не могу докопаться как, потому что идет просчет через js как я понимаю.
Кто может подсказать как сделать?

Comment: Элементы абсолютно позиционируются поверх изображения, позиция указывается в процентах. Так же сделано и в примере, никакого js'а не нужно.

Comment: Если вы консоль откроете, то в примере четко видно, что инлайново эти кружки смещаются , вопрос только зачем тогда?и делается там это именно через js

Comment: @Deniskins с чего вы взяли, что они там js-ом смещаются? Там точно так же заданы позиции точек в процентах и они остаются неизменны при изменении размера

Comment: в том примере нету SVG но можно на svg это сделать и эффект пульсации тоже ...

Comment: Я просто смотрел на консоль и на то, что там меняется инлайново на этих элементах, а значит через js было. И я так понял, что js там используется для тултипов по клику на эти кружки. И мне тултипы тоже будут нужны.

Comment: да и при съужении окошка все точки плывут

Comment: Что плывут не заметил..Хотя сужал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хочу добавить ещё один нюанс. Многие знают, что можно использовать `tooltip` SVG, который выводится при наведении курсора на объект. Чтобы это работало, нужно объект svg обернуть групповыми тегами `<g>` и поместить внутрь теги `<title>`

```
<g>
 <title> Первая     позиция установки раковины </title> 
 <path>..... </path> 
</g>
```

Оказывается можно делать вложенные `<title>` получая много строчные комментарии

В примере ниже взят код @Stranger in the Q и добавлены много строчные `tooltip`

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
circle {
  fill:red;
  transition:200ms;
  cursor:pointer;
  stroke: transparent;
}

g:hover circle, g:hover path {
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg);
  
}

g:hover circle{
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke: white;
}

path {
  stroke: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition:200ms;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-100 -50 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJW6o.png" 
         x="-100" y="-100" height="200" width="200" />
  <g transform="translate(-45,-2)">
    <title> Первая  позиция установки раковины
   <title>Крепление к каркасу     
   </title>
 </title>
    <circle r="5"/>
  <path d="M2,0L-2,0M0,-2L0,2"/>
 </g>
     <g transform="translate(-14.5,-15)"> 
    <title> Вторая позиция установки раковины
     <title>Крепление к каркасу     
     </title>
 </title>
    <circle r="5"/>
     <path d="M2,0L-2,0M0,-2L0,2"/>
 </g>
 <g transform="translate(60,-1)">
   <title> Третья позиция установки раковины
    <title>Крепление к каркасу     
    </title>
 </title>
   <circle r="5"/>
    <path d="M2,0L-2,0M0,-2L0,2"/>
 </g>
    
<svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот вариант с использованием `svg`

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
circle {
  fill:red;
  transition:200ms;
  cursor:pointer;
  stroke: transparent;
}

g:hover circle, g:hover path {
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg);
  
}

g:hover circle{
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke: white;
}

path {
  stroke: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition:200ms;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-100 -50 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJW6o.png" 
         x="-100" y="-100" height="200" width="200" />
  <g transform="translate(-45,-2)"><circle r="5"/><path d="M2,0L-2,0M0,-2L0,2"/></g>
  <g transform="translate(60,-1)"><circle r="5"/><path d="M2,0L-2,0M0,-2L0,2"/></g>
  <g transform="translate(-14.5,-15)"><circle r="5"/><path d="M2,0L-2,0M0,-2L0,2"/></g>
<svg>
```

Comment: что я и предлогал ...:))

Comment: @MaximLensky да, но должны еще набежать любители сделать все на `html + css`, ничего не имею против однако предпочитаю сразу делать на `svg`, потому что сегодня просят кружочки, а завтра попросят чтобы у них был градиентный бордер или еще какая нибудь другая дичь

Comment: -))Спс за ответ.

Comment: @Deniskins Всегда пожалуйста

Comment: щас по моему вообще весь сайт можно лепить в SVG почти ВСЁ

Comment: @MaximLensky сайты сайтами, я веб приложения делаю, редакторы там всякие, карты, глобусы, визуализацию разную

Comment: @MaximLensky Максим, наверное ты видел была здесь на сайте обзорная статья на тему [Можно ли весь сайт сделать на SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/753664/28748) там есть и интереснейший ответ от Константина на эту тему

Comment: @Alexandr_TT mesh давно же появился ..и  хорошо поддерживался ..просто он гемеройный ..и не так просто его сжать было ..я пользовался пару раз им

Comment: @MaximLensky так это было только в экспериментальных технологиях Chrome и Леа Веру продвигала его вместе со своими плагинами для конических градиентов. Если появилось в финальных документах и примут до конца спецификацию SVG2, то надеюсь будут поддерживать все браузеры, кроме `IE` разумеется

Comment: @Alexandr_TT. Я ещё у него работал когда делал яблоко на mesh  мне не очень понравилось , забыл поздоровпться

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Привет Павел! Давно не было тебя слышно ((((

Comment: @Alexandr_TT. Да блин шеф меня на ноль умножил, щас почти концы с концами свожу, буду просится к нему

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Ну он вроде не против сейчас, писал он недавно как-то в комментариях

Comment: @Alexandr_TT серьёзно ? Я аж поослезился , если возьмёт назад буду молчать блин...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский давай в наш чатик, если хочешь пообщаться немного, пока модераторы по башке не настучали за офтопик А здесь давай почистим за собой

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Так тебе вроде репа позволяет баллотироваться в модеры ммми ? Ладно я это всё , ухожу пошёл я домой к Максу схожа