# В каком виде дизайнер должен передавать верстальщику изображения SVG

Tags: вёрстка, svg

Никак не могу найти ответы на некоторые нюансы касаемо svg. Кто должен создавать svg? Допустим есть макет, который необходимо сверстать... Логотипы и иконки не предоставлены дизайнером в svg. Или если есть, то код svg с ошибками. Что должен делать верстальщик в таком случае?

а) Жаловаться дизайнеру/заказчику?
b) вставлять png/иконочные шрифты?
c) писать сам svg?

Кто пишет код svg от руки, а не рисует? Входит ли это все в обязанности верстальщика/фронтендера (a не дизайнера, например)? В полном ли объеме.

Вот пример кода полученного от дизайнера сделанного в фотошопе

```html
<symbol viewBox="0 0 62 38.5" id="dd-1">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .acls-1{opacity:.6}.acls-2,.acls-3{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px}.acls-3{fill-rule:evenodd}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="aторговый" class="acls-1">
        <path id="aПрямоугольник_22" data-name="Прямоугольник 22" class="acls-2" d="M.5 14h18v8H.5z"/>
        <path id="aПрямоугольник_22_копия" data-name="Прямоугольник 22 копия" class="acls-2" d="M.5 21h18v8H.5z"/>
        <path id="aПрямоугольник_22_копия_2" data-name="Прямоугольник 22 копия 2" class="acls-2"
              d="M43.5 21h18v8h-18z"/>
        <path id="aФигура_87" data-name="Фигура 87" class="acls-3" d="M682 77v-1h26v1h-26z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_88" data-name="Фигура 88" class="acls-3"
              d="M682 70a23.828 23.828 0 0 1 12-3 30.611 30.611 0 0 1 13 3" transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_89" data-name="Фигура 89" class="acls-3" d="M682 83s4.362 2 12 2a40.779 40.779 0 0 0 13-2"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_90" data-name="Фигура 90" class="acls-3" d="M682 89s2.289 3 9 3"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_92" data-name="Фигура 92" class="acls-3" d="M690 59h1v34h-1V59z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_92_копия" data-name="Фигура 92 копия" class="acls-3" d="M697 59h1v34h-1V59z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_92_копия_2" data-name="Фигура 92 копия 2" class="acls-3" d="M703 60h1v32h-1V60z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_92_копия_3" data-name="Фигура 92 копия 3" class="acls-3" d="M685 60h1v32h-1V60z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_93" data-name="Фигура 93" class="acls-3" d="M682 70h-1v-7h1v7z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_94" data-name="Фигура 94" class="acls-3" d="M708 70h-1v-7h1v7z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_95" data-name="Фигура 95" class="acls-3" d="M681 63s1.75-4 13-4 14 4 14 4"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_96" data-name="Фигура 96" class="acls-3" d="M670 70h1v13h-1V70z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_96_копия" data-name="Фигура 96 копия" class="acls-3" d="M676 70h1v13h-1V70z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_96_копия_2" data-name="Фигура 96 копия 2" class="acls-3" d="M712 70h1v13h-1V70z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_96_копия_3" data-name="Фигура 96 копия 3" class="acls-3" d="M718 70h1v13h-1V70z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_97" data-name="Фигура 97" class="acls-3" d="M681 63h-1v-4h1v4z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_98" data-name="Фигура 98" class="acls-3" d="M709 63h-1v-4h1v4z"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_99" data-name="Фигура 99" class="acls-3" d="M680 60s1.958-4.484 14-4.484S709 60 709 60"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aФигура_91" data-name="Фигура 91" class="acls-3" d="M707 90s-1.215 3-10 3"
              transform="translate(-663.5 -55)"/>
        <path id="aПрямоугольник_21" data-name="Прямоугольник 21" class="acls-2" d="M.5 14h18v21H.5z"/>
        <path id="aПрямоугольник_21_копия" data-name="Прямоугольник 21 копия" class="acls-2"
              d="M43.5 14h18v21h-18z"/>
    </g>
</symbol>
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не связан с программированием. Вопрос о должностных обязанностях конкретного человека в конкретной компании

Comment: Ну если они не предоставлены в svg, то используйте как есть. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @HamSter поддерживаю. Я всегда отправляю этот вопрос дизайнерам.

Comment: Если я буду за дизайнеров рисовать svg, то пусть они за меня пишут мой код. И разница в том, что (пусть криво) я нарисую, а они и одной строчки из себя не выдавят. Так что нагибайте их по полной.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Очень выручили..

Comment: @Виктор Вы разве не видели,  когда давали голос против,что вопрос переоформлен уже и направлен в другое русло

Comment: @andreymal Вы разве не видели, когда давали голос против, что вопрос переоформлен уже и направлен в другое русло

Comment: @Alexandr_T вы разве не видите, что чужой вопрос вы дополнили своим кодом 3 часа назад, а голоса за закрытие вопрос ловил 16 часов назад. 16-3=13. Вы опоздали на 13 часов

Comment: @Виктор насчет вашего голоса я может и ошибаюсь, но я четко видел только три голоса за закрытие, когда начал писать ответ, делал это долго, с перерывами и был неприятный сюрприз, когда из редактора опубликовал свой ответ. Вопрос сейчас ведь по делу, половина проблем идет от неумения дизайнеров создавать грамотно SVG изображения.

Comment: @Alexandr_T На мой взгляд ничего не изменилось, вопрос как был про обязанности,  так и остался про обязанности. Вопрос не об неумении, а о служебных обязанностях, а знать мы этого не можем не изучив трудовой договор автора, а это уже юридическая плоскость.

Comment: Я что-то не понял, откуда, почему и зачем взялся какой-то пример svg, если его добавил не автор вопроса?

Comment: @andreymal я добавил, а что это запрещено правилами? добавить код, для примера, если его там не было.

Comment: @Alexandr_T ну фиг знает, мы же вроде как не знаем, что за дизайнер у автора вопроса и какие svg он ему даёт, или используется ли фотошоп вообще; вы попытались это додумать за автора, я не думаю что это хорошо

Comment: о, тоже было такое, что дизайнер из фотошопа плагином достал иконки в svg, невозможно работать с таким, после просьбы 3-ей прислать адекватный svg отказалась продолжать работу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос на самом деле хороший, актуальный, но надо немного под другим углом его задать:

**В каком виде дизайнер должен передавать верстальщику изображения SVG.**

Какие требования по содержанию кода SVG должны быть предъявлены дизайнеру.
Ведь изображение можно рисовать совершенно по разному и многие проблемы верстальщика идут от исходного кода, порою просто невозможно реализовать поставленную задачу.

Например:

- иконка нарисована лепкой, а не одиночными линиями, поэтому невозможно
  будет сделать анимацию.
- Растровое изображение в векторном формате   обернуто в SVG. Поэтому очень затруднительно стилизовать его стилями CSS. Только с применением фильтров.

см. [Задать цвет картинке svg в файле со стилями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/755510/28748)

- Изображение в векторном редакторе нормально открывается, а в
  приложении не попадает в поле видимости.
- Изображение нарисовано в фотошопе и сохранено плагином в SVG. Код на
  выходе просто ужасный.
  [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/649764/28748)
- Невозможно изменить стили иконки с помощью обычных правил css.

  `fill`, `stroke` и т.д.
  К примеру,- стремление дизайнера к оригинальности порой доходит до абсурда. Вместо использования стандартных иконок меньше по весу 1к, типа галочки, он создаёт свой "шедевр" в растровом редакторе и сохраняет в формате base64.

  [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759453/28748)

Конечно, чтобы грамотно предъявить эти требования дизайнеру, необходимо верстальщику освоить начальные знания по SVG самому.

Comment: Спасибо за правку и подробный ответ. Как всегда выручаете!)

Comment: _"уникальные идентификаторы на русском языке, поэтому не будут работать"_ - с чего бы им не работать?

Comment: @Qwertiy это я погорячился :) вчера столкнулся с этим, что работают id на русском, когда SVG в HTML добавлено. Сейчас уберу это спорное утверждение. Но помнишь наш давний спор по SVG - парсер в HTML пропускает ошибки SVG,  а если запускать в браузере чисто файл SVG, то выдается сообщение об ошибке и останавливается выполнение файла. Помнишь viewbox вместо view**B**ox  :)

Comment: Да, с парсером есть отличия... Но юникод, тем более в id уж точно должны все уметь.

Comment: я добавлю еще после сборки, в спрайте такие svg нужно еще вручную перекраивать, ооочень много левых атрибутов тянет - Сизифов труд вообщем. Думаю только в иллюстраторе все можно настроить и svg сжатое оптимизированное получить.

Comment: @HamSter С наступающим Вас Новым годом! Искренне желаю, чтобы у вас всё сбылось и получилось,-  чего хотите, о чём мечтаете.                О данном топике: здесь речь идет не об общих проблемах SVG и даже не о спрайтах, а о том, каким элементарным требованиям должен отвечать файл svg, нарисованный дизайнером А насчет спрайтов, веб пак при соответствующих настройках удаляет все атрибуты , в частности `fill`, `stroke`

Comment: @Alexandr_T, Спасибо, и Вас с наступающим Новым ГОдом!=) Взаимно, успехов во всех начинаниях! Я gulp'ом собираю, вроде, настраиваю тоже на оптимизацию, но почему-то именно с svg содранных с photoshop были проблемы.

Comment: @HamSter да, именно так, поэтому и привел пример с плагина фотошопа. так как фотошоп не подозревает о механизме наследовании свойств в svg и получается такая каша, что без бутылки не разобраться. Половина не работает. Я таких примеров получаю десятки от дизайнеров. Вывод один, вы правильно заметили,- рисовать дизайнерам нужно в векторных редакторах