# Иконки из png в svg. Кто должен делать? Верстальщик или дизайнер?

Tags: вёрстка, svg, icon, png

В вёрстке относительно недавно. Подскажите, как правильно поступить?

Дизайнеры к макету не прикладывают иконки в svg, соответственно я использую png, что в макете. Но по макету на иконки часто разные эффекты ховер (смена цвета например). Получается намного проще использовать svg + иконочный шрифт. 
Возможно, быстро и качественно, перевести иконки из png в svg? Я пробовал это сделать в Ai но получается какая-то каша. 
Или это задача дизайнера и он должен предоставить свои иконки в svg?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не относится к программированию, а больше внутреннему порядку компании...

Comment: Конечно же ***дизайнер***

Comment: Хорошо если верстальщик умеет это делать, но вообще этот момент как раз больше к дизайнеру. Хотя тут многогранная ситуация, если за эту работу платят дополнительно и вы это умеете делать, вай нот?

Comment: @Григорий вопрос актуальный, посмотрите вот этот топик - "В каком виде дизайнер должен передавать верстальщику изображения SVG"  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758473/28748

Comment: HTTPS://Vectorizer.io